# Adding more webservices to C# app seems to slow startup

Tags: c#, web-services, service

I have a C# app that calls 5 different web services.
Originally the app called 1 service and started fairly quickly.
But I am noticing as more services are being add the start up the app takes longer and longer.
The app is not using the services for anything until the form renders. This is all happening during the init process.

Is this normal behavior for apps using web services?

Comment: I'm not sure why the close votes.  The OP is asking a reasonable question: Is there startup overhead **in general** when a project has web service references, before these services are directly invoked from user code.  No specific code is needed to answer the question.

Comment: Are  you talking about _WCF services_?  If so, then _yes_ - the mere act of creating a client proxy (even if you don't use them till later) can take some time. This can be reduced with [channel caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh314046(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @user1441213: Please update your question to indicate whether you are calling WCF services, or if not, exactly what you are calling and how.

Comment: @EricJ. It is not entirely clear what sort of clients OP is using nor what he refers to as "web services" - _WCF; old-skool_ `[webmethod]`s or even _.NET Remoting_ (not my view though) - hence close vote.

Comment: @Micky: With new users, I personally tend to leave a comment explaining what they need to do in order to improve the question before downvoting and/or voting to close, if the question is missing some detail but otherwise reasonable.  I leave the question open in a separate browser tab and check on it in a bit.

Comment: @EricJ. Same.  Hence my first comment above to which you beat me to it by 2 minutes as I was typing and looking up a link.  ;)

Comment: Yes - WCF. The app is reaching out to a LAMP server using NuSoap.